# CSS to set post excerpt and title to float beside featured image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the post title and post excerpt to align under the date beside the featured image but I am only able to set the date but not the title and except.

This is my CSS for the date which is a simple float:

```
.post-thumbnail {
  width: 24%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="post-meta group">
        <p class="post-category"><?php the_category(' / '); ?></p>
        <p class="post-date"><?php the_time('j M, Y'); ?></p>
    </div><!--/.post-meta-->

    <h2 class="post-title">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h2><!--/.post-title-->

    <?php if (ot_get_option('excerpt-length') != '0'): ?>
    <div class="entry excerpt">             
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!--/.entry-->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

When I add `float: left` to the class `.post-meta` it moves the title and excerpt but not aligned under the post meta.

This is my new www.gazetbits.com. Any guide would be appreciated or would it be correct to group the title and post except into a Div and apply the float.

Thanks

Comment: not sure why the hyperlink isn't working

Comment: Hi Siyah, its a WordPress theme, all files are PHP. I wasn't sure if i was to post this here or at the WordPress site.

Comment: I see what you mean, i have added that bit of the code

Comment: the html provided doesn't include the `post-meta` element, or thumbnail for that matter

Comment: sorry, it was there but I forgot to format it, so it didn't show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.post-meta` takes too much height. I achieved your desired behavior adding this rule:

```
.post-meta {
    height: 22px;
}
```

**or** changing the display type:

```
.post-meta {
    display: table;
}
```